# How to set a default Seq[Seo] if there is no result from databases?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How to set a default `Seq[Seo]` if there is no result from databases?

```
case class Seo( page: String, title: String, desc: String)

object Seo {

  val pageseo = {
      get[String]("seo.page") ~
      get[String]("seo.title") ~
      get[String]("seo.desc") map {
      case page~title~desc => Seo (page, title, desc)
    }

  }

  def getSeo(page : String) : Seq[Seo] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from seo where page = {page}").on('page -> page).as(Seo.pageseo *)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy our solution from the Play mailing-list ;)

```
  def getSeo(page: String): Seq[Seo] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from seo where page = {page}").on('page -> page).as(Seo.pageseo *)
    } match {
      case Nil => Seq(Seo("London", "hello", "o"))
      case result => result
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks :) was going to post but I don't have the permissions just yet :)